# How to write a log in to a text file for debugging purpose using objective C?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, debugging, file-io

I want to debug the login process in my app and want to evaluate the results when developing my application.

The login process contains the basic things like user name and password and I want the result of this and the other credentials to be stored in a file.

So how to accomplish this while developing the application and not using the breakpoints all the time.

Thank you.

Comment: What exactly do you need help with? Opening a text file for writing? Getting access to the logger from all the parts of your application? Writing to the text file?

Answer (score 5):

Without knowing more, `NSLog` will likely do.

---

Ahh... OK. This'll do what you want (boiler plate anyway) while continuing to support full on `NSString` formatting.

.... somewhere, declare a global ....

```
NSFileHandle *logFile = nil;
```

... initialization code ....

```
logFile = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForWritingAtPath: ...string containing path...];
```

... the actual log function ....

```
void MyLog(NSString *format, ...) {
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, format);
    NSString *formattedString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat: format
                                                  arguments: args];
    va_end(args);
    [logFile writeData: [formattedString dataUsingEncoding: NSNEXTSTEPStringEncoding]];
    [formattedString release];
}
```

Comment: I want to write into a text file, not just print it on the console

Answer (score 4):

you could redirect the stderr (this is where NSLog puts its messages) to a file.

```
+ (void)redirectNSLogToFile {
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *logPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"console.log"];
    freopen([logPath cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding],"a+",stderr);
}
```

Comment: Neat trick, but it is a bad idea to mess about with the file descriptors created by the app.

Comment: +1 for giving a working solution.i am using this method for debugging multiple applications at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSError *error;
NSMutableString *logstr = [ [NSMutableString alloc] init ];

// write info to logstr here

[ logstr writeToFile:@"file.log" atomically:YES encoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding error:&error ];
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at [Log4Cocoa](http://log4cocoa.sourceforge.net/).